# Regex match failing in GNU grep on Windows Server

Tags: regex, grep, windows-server, mintty

Here's the head of my file:

```
id,date,section,identifier,action,level,user_id,week,month,seconds_since_start
9464384,334600,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,1
9464413,334626,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,1
9464430,334659,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,1
9464470,334692,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,1
9464560,334772,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,1
9464756,335003,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,-1
```

I am having trouble using grep and simple regular expressions from mintty (as installed with git) on Windows Server 2016

I want to know if any lines end with a minus number, so the command I was hoping would work was:

```
 grep '-[0-9]+$' file.csv
```

That finds no matches. I can simplify the regex even further, this one also finds no matches:

```
grep '1$' file.csv
```

I have tried replacing single ticks with double (following [here](https://superuser.com/a/550175/166855)), and replacing grep with egrep, but those changes make no difference.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: These PowerShell commands do work: `Select-String -Path .\file.csv -Pattern '1$'` & `Select-String -Path .\file.csv -Pattern '-[0-9]+$'`

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:** Your pattern begins with a hyphen, which makes it ambiguous to grep.  Is it a command line option, or is it a regexp?  The `-e` option of `grep` specifically tells grep that the next option is the regexp to use.  Similarly, `--` tells grep that no more command-line options follow, therefore the next argument is the regexp.

I don't have access to a Windows machine, but FreeBSD's `grep` reports an error on your first example:

```
$ grep '-[0-9]+$' file.csv
grep: invalid option -- [
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

`grep` is seeing the `-[...` string as a quoted command-line option, and reports an error because `grep` has no `-[` option.

Your second command succeeds on BSD:

```
$ grep '1$' file.csv
9464384,334600,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,1
9464413,334626,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,1
9464430,334659,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,1
9464470,334692,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,1
9464560,334772,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,1
9464756,335003,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,-1
```

For these two reasons, I would submit that your `grep` implementation may be broken.

**Problem 2:** Your regexp uses Extended regexp syntax, and grep defaults to Basic regexp syntax.  The [FreeBSD man page for `egrep`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=egrep&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) describes a key difference between Basic and Extended regexps:

> In basic regular expressions the metacharacters ?, +, {, |, (, and )
>    lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?,
>    \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).

You need to use either the `-E` option to get `grep` to parse it as an extended regexp, or else escape the `+` with a backslash:

```
$ grep -- '-[0-9]+$' file.csv
$ grep -E -- '-[0-9]+$' file.csv
9464756,335003,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,-1
$ grep -- '-[0-9]\+$' file.csv
9464756,335003,12,,complete,4,1124822691805,1,1,-1
```